# Send an integer into a server with GET method

Tags: mysql, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection, getmethod

I've been researching this problem for a while now and have been trying to use the POST method until recently when I figured out that the GET method will be sufficient for what I need to do. 
My objective: 
   Take an integer from my app and send it into a php server to save it

For now, I just need to send one integer to get it working and to have a starting point to work from. Once I start getting the ball rolling and things start working, I will be sending maybe 20 integers maximum at a time, so I don't believe that I will have a problem with the data amount restrictions on the GET method.

I am working with a friend on this project right now because I am not as fluent in php, I have been exposed to it several times though, so I should know most of the terminology involved. ANYWAY, here is my php code that my friend wrote for me...

```
<?php
// A sample php file to demo passing parameters and getting POST data.
// This simply appends the specified value to the end of the 'sample' table.
// Call it like this: sample.php?val=4
//    where 4 is the value you want to append to the table
// The code returns whether or not the sql query was performed with success or not.
//    If successful, a boolean true (or 1) is returned.
//    If not, then an error message is returned with the sql error.

   include 'dbConnect.php';

   $val = $_GET["val"];  // value to set to

   $sql=
   "INSERT INTO sample (`test`)
   VALUES ('" . $val . "')
   ";

   $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
   if(!$result){
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

   echo $val+1;

   mysql_close($con);

?>
```

This code takes the sent value for the variable "val" and echoes that value plus one (so that the setting and the getting values are different from the site so I can more easily tell if my code works) This should work right?

Next, I believe I haven't quite finished the Xcode portion of the project yet, but I have a successful connection happening, I just haven't been able to change the value of the variable in the php server. In my project, I have an NSInteger variable called "num" and its value, set by the text field in my app, is the one I want to send in to the server. I also am using a button (called "postPressed") to initiate the function of the sending process. So here is my code...

```
NSURLRequest *request;
NSURLConnection *connection;
NSURL *url;

NSInteger num;



- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


- (IBAction)valueChange:(id)sender {
    num = [_valueTF.text intValue];
}


- (IBAction)postPressed:(id)sender {
    url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://jrl.teamdriven.us/source/scripts/2013/sample.php?val=%d", num]];
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    if (request) {
        connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        _returnLbl.text = @"success!";
    }

}
```

My returnLbl does change to be "success", so I know the connection works, I just think I'm missing some code on the setting the variable part. Please help me out, this has been a thorn in my side for about a month now. Also, I apologize for the length of this question, I'm just trying to get in all the details so that there doesn't have to be any clarifications.

Comment: Someone will probably come along and explain these both in greater detail but... 1. **Don't use `mysql_` functions!** and 2. **You're vulnerable to SQL injection**.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that my code worked the whole time, it's just that when I looked up the data table generated by phpMyAdmin, I did not happen to notice that there was a page two of data because I had tested it so much in my browser. The integers were sent and saved successfully with the code above. I apologize for posting something like this and finding out how dumb of a mistake it truly was, but if anyone would like to give me any kinds of improvements, I am open to them. Thank you for taking your time to view this question.